# Installing Vuze on Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, software-compatibility

I've trying to install Vuze on Raspberry Pi 4 8GB with Ubuntu Mate 20.10 OS and it just doesn't work, i'm getting errors about that it has some libraries missing and that it cannot read .so file.
Does anyone can help?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What steps did you take to install it? Have you updated apt before installing? Is Vuze supported on ARM?

Comment: Yes, I did, Vuze doesn't seem to be in any repository, they say it has a Snap package but when I searched for it, it said that there is no version for arm processor.
Then I tried to download the zip file and install it myself, I can't show the exact error message because I'm not at my home at the moment, i'll be tomorrow.

Comment: To save time - if your system is reporting *no version for arm processor* you are stuck till RPT/RPF move from Arm processors!  Back to the source code and compile. NO I do not recommend running x86 emulation on a Pi.  Voting to close (or I would if I had not clicked the wrong option <blush>)

Comment: The thing is that Vuze is written in Java… it should be multi-platform

Comment: "*it should be multi-platform*" - why do you wrote then "*it said that there is no version for arm processor*"?

Comment: exactly, this is the confusing part… I don't understand either